# java.lang.AssertionError ao buscar o conteúdo de um input no Jbehave

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

Olá, tudo bem?
Estou utilizando o Jbehave + Selenium para testar um programa em que se calcula a área [programa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzPOV.png), porém ao buscar o valor da área (onde se encontra o 6), ele retorna o seguinte erro: (java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<6> but was:<[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (b4c56353d7a60a84b9c1de3bf0fae224)] -> id: area]>), ou seja, busca o local de armazenamento da varíavel e não o conteúdo do input AREA.

Trecho do código:
@Then("a área calculada será $resultado")
public void resultadoArea(String resultado) throws InterruptedException {

```
    WebElement atual = navegar.findElement(By.id("area"));
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(resultado, atual);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!
Não é possível buscar o atributo com o getAtributte na declaração da variável atual por ser um WebElement, a declaração tinha que ser feita no assertEquals

```
@Then("a área calculada será $area")
public void resultadoArea(String resultado) throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement atual = navegar.findElement(By.id("area"));
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(resultado, atual.getAttribute("value"));
}
```